# How to a define a name for a type of variable that is a constant sized array?

Tags: c, data-structures, typedef

I have to do a program for college and I need to use two files with the tree and row data structure.
At the beginning I have a definition for the data each data structure is supposed to comport:

```
#define TYPE int
```

Which is implemented in the code appropriately.

Though in this task I need to fill these structures with names up to 20 char's and I don't want to change all my code either to use vectors or to be able to allocate space for a dynamic array with `TYPE` as `char*`.

Is there any way I could do something like define a 20 char long array like this?

```
#define TYPE char[20]
```

Comment: Note that "with names up to 20 chars" the array needs to hold 21 characters, to include the `NUL` terminator. You also say "I don't want to change all my code" but in many projects, the unwelcome but wise decision is sometimes "start again". That's one reason why you should build your code in small steps and not rush forwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `typedef` instead of `#define` because `typedef` can handle arrays (and pointers) where `#define` cannot.

```
typedef int TYPE;

typedef char TYPE[20];
```

etc.

Continue to use `TYPE` in your structures, etc.